# Error while configuring python in apache2

Tags: 10.10, python, apache2

I was trying to configure python to apache2 as suggested by http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=91101

1. First downloaded and installed and enabled `mod_python` module
2. Changed `/etc/apache2/sites-available/default` as specified

   ```
   <Directory /var/www/>
       Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
       AllowOverride AuthConfig
       Order allow,deny
       allow from all

       AddHandler mod_python .py
       PythonHandler mod_python.publisher
       PythonDebug On

       # Uncomment this directive is you want to see apache2's
       # default start page (in /apache2-default) when you go to /
       #RedirectMatch ^/$ /apache2-default/
   </Directory>
   ```
3. created `test.py` in my `/var/www` and restarted apache.
4. Getting `404-Not Found error` for `localhost/test.py`
5. On my `error.log` i have

   > [Sun Apr 10 14:07:04 2011] [notice] mod_python (pid=5591, interpreter='localhost.localdomain'): Importing module '/var/www/test.py'

I am using `Ubuntu-10.10`. Anyone any ideas ???

**UPDATE**
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the folder is `/var/www` and NOT /www/var.

Did you add:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

As the first line in your python script?
If not it won't be recognized as a python script.

Also try to disable the plugin and tell me if it outputs the contents of the file when you go to `localhost/test.py`.

I hope this helped you,
Daniel

Comment: thanks for your interest @Daniel0108, but still i m getting the above error-page.

Comment: did you disable the plugin and tried to open the script?

Comment: you mean changing the to the conf file or disabling the module??

Comment: have you checked the file permissions?
perhaps you should try to set the file with 777 and give it a go..

Comment: @experimentX yes, disable the module and try to open the file. if it outputs the source of the script, it's okay, if not, the file isn't online.

Comment: @PavlosG @Daniel0105 when it prompts me to download file.

Comment: @experimentX: please tell us how you solved the problem ;)

Comment: i think it was working from the first. first i put `print "hello"` .. it gave me 404 error. and then i put `def index(req):
  return "Test successful";` it gave me test successful. I am total newbie. perhaps i should go though an ebook or so.